# convert a list to dictionary and add duplicate key values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to find the dict value like this

```
{'deepak': 0, 'nayak': 0}
```

I tried in this way

```
d={}
d['deepak'] = 0
d['nayak'] = 0 
f = [ '1, deepak, 15',
'2, nayak, 10',
 '3, deepak, 10',
 '4, nayak, 13']
for lines in f:
print(lines)
##appropriate logic to excute#
    print(d)
```

Expected o/p should be

```
{'deepak': 25, 'nayak': 23}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much there

```py
d = {}

f = [ '1, deepak, 15',
'2, nayak, 10',
 '3, deepak, 10',
 '4, nayak, 13']

for line in f:
    # by splitting on the comma and trailing space
    # you can unpack those three entries into a throw-away var,
    # k, and v and you only need to convert v to int
    _, k, v = line.split(', ')
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + int(v)

d
{'deepak': 25, 'nayak': 23}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` from the `collections` module, to cut down on some boilerplate needed when using a regular dict

```
from collections import Counter

f = [
    '1, deepak, 15',
    '2, nayak, 10',
    '3, deepak, 10',
    '4, nayak, 13'
]

result = Counter()

for x in f:
    _, name, count = x.split(', ')
    result[name] += int(count)

print(result)
```

Comment: `defaultdict(int)` also accomplishes the same goal. By *cutting down on boilerplate* is it just that those particular data structures are better optimized to holding the given value? I haven't delved into the source as much as I probably should

Comment: Yes `Counter` can be thought of as a special case of `defaultdict`, with extra functionality and optimizations that makes sense when you know it holds an int as its value. I originally wrote my answer using `defaultdict` but then realised that `Counter` would be a better choice.

Comment: Makes sense, especially with additional functions for sorting and returning most common values

Answer (score 1):

```py
d={}
d['deepak'] = 0
d['nayak'] = 0 
f = [ '1, deepak, 15',
'2, nayak, 10',
 '3, deepak, 10',
 '4, nayak, 13']
for lines in f:
    print(lines)
    ##appropriate logic to excute#
    line = lines.split(', ')
    d[line[1]] += int(line[-1])
print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks,__Yes, I am trying to do in this wayand I pretty much close to this logic `d[line[1]] += int(line[-1])`